# What's the difference between MDLVertexDescriptor and MTLVertexDescriptor?

Tags: ios, metal

What's the difference between MDLVertexDescriptor and MTLVertexDescriptor for Metal? I wonder why there are 2 different data structures to define a vertex descriptor?

Comment: They both represent vertex descriptors, but they do it for different frameworks. You can use one another interchangeably, since if you are using Model I/O you aren't necessarily using Metal and vice versa. So there are two of them so that Apple frameworks aren't tightly coupled for no reason other then similarity of some classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MDLVertexDescriptor` is an interface that is located in Model I/O framework.

`MTLVertexDescriptor` is an interface that is located in Metal framework.

Even though both of them are a similar concept (a description of how vertex data is laid out), they need to be separate for the following reasons.

First of all, you **can** link against both of aforementioned frameworks, but you are not **required** to use either one of them.

For example, let's say I need to write an app that loads a model and draws it, but I don't want to learn Metal, so I just stick to OpenGL. And Model I/O framework suits my needs. In this case, I would link against Model I/O and OpenGL, but not Metal, so I won't have `MTLVertexDescriptor`.

On the other hand, let's say I need to write an application that loads, let's say, a glTF 2.0 (https://www.khronos.org/gltf/) model and since I know that OpenGL is deprecated by Apple, I want to use Metal Framework. In this case, I will link against Metal framework and some other library that can load glTF files, but I don't need Model I/O, since I use glTF. So, in this case, I won't have `MDLVertexDescriptor`.

Both interfaces are pretty similar, since they both represent the same thing, but the differences are somewhat domain-specific.

But the main reason, I think, why these are different classes is that Apple decided that introducing similar concepts to both frameworks is better than just separating all the "similar" concepts into one framework, because that would be harder to maintain, document and just work around.